# Most useful stored procedures for a new DBA?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am a new DBA working with several more experienced DBA's.  When I am scratching my head one of them says "oh just run SP_xx_xx", and sure enough that begins the path to solution.

Of course they all just know them, I have decided to start a list.  I have not been writting them all down, so all I have in my list is these three.

- sp_Cycle_Errorlog
- sp_whoisactive
- sp_change_users_login 'report'

I Googled and came up with some very old lists

- [Useful system stored procedures in SQL Server(SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578454/useful-system-stored-procedures-in-sql-server)
- [Two Dozen of My Favorite System Stored Procedures, By Kiely, Don](http://www.codemag.com/article/0505041)

What are the best or most helpful Stored Procedures for a New DBA to have in their tool kit, for SQL 2012/2014?

Answer (score 9):

> What are the best or most helpful Stored Procedures for a New DBA to have in their tool kit, for SQL 2012/2014?

You are asking Tools that are most useful to DBA

In no particuliar order ...

- Brent Ozar Crew has [sp_Blitz®, sp_BlitzCache®, sp_BlitzIndex®, sp_AskBrent®, sp_BlitzRS™, sp_BlitzTrace™](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/sql-server-downloads/) - This helps to do health check for sql servers.
- To migrate sql server from one server to another use [powershell - dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) [it migrates over 25 components] from Chrissy LeMaire
- To document sql server use - [SQL Power Doc](https://sqlpowerdoc.codeplex.com/) from kendalvandyke
- For login transfer use [Transferring Logins](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/Scripts/dba_CopyLogins.sql) - By SQLSoldier
- Monitoring SQL Server use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) from Adam Machanic
- Analyzing Query plans - use [SQL Sentry's Free Plan Explorer](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer)

**The inbuild system SP are limited to what they can report or show. The best way is to create your own (use existing ones and build your own <-- make sure you give proper credit ! ) using DMVs.**

e.g. sp_who is way ancient vs sp_whoisactive is what you will install on your server to quickly findout whats going on with the server.

Remove `sp_change_users_login 'report'` as it is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx). Instead you should use `ALTER USER`